# How do i point my view element to an existing view?

Tags: view

I have a view element in my module e.g.

'View List="Lists/Cars" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="FullPage1" WebPartOrder="0"'

I want to point this to an existing view e.g. MyView100, so i dont have create all the xml.

I cant use the listviewwebpart as i am in a sandbox.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `DefaultView` and `BaseViewID` (Where the `BaseViewID` is something other than 0)

```
<View List="Lists/Cars" BaseViewID="1" WebPartZoneID="FullPage1" WebPartOrder="0" DefaultView="FALSE" BaseViewID="1" />
```

More info on what's possible on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms430995.aspx

Comment: Does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try this post from Waldek Mastykarz: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/modifying-views-list-view-web-part-sandboxed-solution/

Comment: Post is no good. It alters the default view, i want to be able to use an existing one.